# How to find the Problem using Crash Report of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, exception, memory, crash

I have the iPhone crash report and I am not able to get what is the problem with that. So, Can any one know what is the problem in the crash report?

```
Incident Identifier: 0C9E5908-BDA9-43B9-8D83-E2EF5E9B75A7
CrashReporter Key:   9cee5ee1497f05fb45986268e8ab8e42fcf2272d
Process:         GRAHAM [94]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D5959B73-09BF-4150-9568-3F86BFA39E9E/GRAHAM.app/GRAHAM
Identifier:      GRAHAM
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-09-08 15:37:41.380 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31dd594c 0x31d46000 + 588108
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31dd593a 0x31d46000 + 588090
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31dd592e 0x31d46000 + 588078
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31deccf8 0x31d46000 + 683256
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ef840 0x3748a000 + 415808
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300166b8 0x3000c000 + 42680
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ecf34 0x3748a000 + 405300
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ecfac 0x3748a000 + 405420
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x374ed0d4 0x3748a000 + 405716
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300165dc 0x3000c000 + 42460
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30292f7e 0x301fd000 + 614270
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30218068 0x301fd000 + 110696
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3020ed98 0x301fd000 + 73112
13  GRAHAM                          0x000035ae 0x1000 + 9646
14  UIKit                           0x308f159c 0x308ed000 + 17820
15  UIKit                           0x308f1174 0x308ed000 + 16756
16  UIKit                           0x309374a8 0x308ed000 + 304296
17  UIKit                           0x30936ce8 0x308ed000 + 302312
18  UIKit                           0x30936874 0x308ed000 + 301172
19  GraphicsServices                0x32046964 0x32041000 + 22884
20  CoreFoundation                  0x30254a70 0x301fd000 + 359024
21  CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 0x301fd000 + 356708
22  UIKit                           0x308f034c 0x308ed000 + 13132
23  UIKit                           0x308eea8c 0x308ed000 + 6796
24  GRAHAM                          0x00002f30 0x1000 + 7984
25  GRAHAM                          0x00002ecc 0x1000 + 7884

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d47158 0x31d46000 + 4440
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d49ed8 0x31d46000 + 16088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3025454e 0x301fd000 + 357710
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 0x301fd000 + 356708
4   WebCore                         0x3588dbc8 0x3580b000 + 535496
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d705a0 0x31d46000 + 173472

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d47990 0x31d46000 + 6544
1   CFNetwork                       0x31b0969a 0x31af1000 + 99994
2   CFNetwork                       0x31b09652 0x31af1000 + 99922
3   CFNetwork                       0x31b0983e 0x31af1000 + 100414
4   CFNetwork                       0x31b09406 0x31af1000 + 99334
5   CFNetwork                       0x31b093f4 0x31af1000 + 99316
6   CFNetwork                       0x31b3cd5c 0x31af1000 + 310620
7   CFNetwork                       0x31b3d25c 0x31af1000 + 311900
8   CFNetwork                       0x31b3d2a8 0x31af1000 + 311976
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3028914e 0x301fd000 + 573774
10  CoreFoundation                  0x302892f8 0x301fd000 + 574200
11  CoreFoundation                  0x302548ec 0x301fd000 + 358636
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 0x301fd000 + 356708
13  Foundation                      0x3055af34 0x30501000 + 368436
14  Foundation                      0x30554062 0x30501000 + 340066
15  Foundation                      0x305023f2 0x30501000 + 5106
16  libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d705a0 0x31d46000 + 173472

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d6b0e0 0x31d46000 + 151776
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3021dd1e 0x301fd000 + 134430
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d705a0 0x31d46000 + 173472

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x39d4d014
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x0017754c      r6: 0x2fffebc4      r7: 0x2fffebd4
    r8: 0x382045bc    r9: 0x0000000a     r10: 0x300f4708     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffebd4      lr: 0x31dd5941      pc: 0x31dd594c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0xdfff +GRAHAM armv6  <7aa74a31836f676ef6a76cbd40b1f71e> /var/mobile/Applications/D5959B73-09BF-4150-9568-3F86BFA39E9E/GRAHAM.app/GRAHAM
   0x3c000 -    0x3dfff  dns.so armv6  <7943354b648b9518f46a835d5359e45a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <384bf84ebe2b822c3cb75fce3e8647d6> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30000000 - 0x30008fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <b404b5f84fa4293f0dd35a469b8b6894> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3000c000 - 0x3015bfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <92636cf8b8e8f3c10721667c48ca182b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x301ca000 - 0x301d8fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <bb2c65d59f36ea2ffdf39aa4d8e49430> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x301fd000 - 0x302a8fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <3e02f5628a56bce4c9eb1c5e49c863d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3036e000 - 0x3038dfff  Bom armv6  <e126f820dc5fc447dafc66aaab19914a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30501000 - 0x305f5fff  Foundation armv6  <c4fc557994aee708dd4fb14ed4fd875f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3071d000 - 0x30729fff  CoreVideo armv6  <5404da375ad190f3e1404e5e8a70f764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3073a000 - 0x30760fff  AppSupport armv6  <1baa1e22eb94eb405d724a2f6b219f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30778000 - 0x3077dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <e4f0b16194fac3bd426e679a3c35c38b> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x308ed000 - 0x31521fff  UIKit armv6  <73cf70d65e1afef2a6ae94fb81bf2fe4> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x316ff000 - 0x31778fff  AddressBookUI armv6  <d3e22e0639428351c4b80a5fa19f7401> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x31885000 - 0x318d1fff  IOKit armv6  <56ba629c062ac21a045914430412c5f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x318e9000 - 0x31aa2fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <80bccae4ab17a49f7fc3a66bb2def894> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31af1000 - 0x31b58fff  CFNetwork armv6  <863076d9b768c76272e3f0f686ca355d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31bb2000 - 0x31bc8fff  OpenGLES armv6  <2c30348868df45d3b8e0e398e0e4f727> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31bcf000 - 0x31cccfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <619918c7282aa5b53ac3ad32c320b7a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31d46000 - 0x31e69fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <f8d95df9776974bbe640911fee96c59d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31ea9000 - 0x31feffff  AudioToolbox armv6  <cd7d22e01299f0d589878c2417c7ff18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32041000 - 0x3204bfff  GraphicsServices armv6  <99b0baa68c257ca5d2fed21bd409ea20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32056000 - 0x32081fff  CoreLocation armv6  <c9dfb15c2c08ee0cc0dcdd70ae3c2c3b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3209b000 - 0x320cefff  Security armv6  <34c21a865d91e9a13477e9395c516f8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x320e8000 - 0x32194fff  ImageIO armv6  <44921d26b2b796c2c707c87c68026b16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x321b3000 - 0x321d9fff  MobileSync armv6  <784e8d709e4dcd3306c6925ad711e629> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x322ce000 - 0x32324fff  GMM armv6  <7c7d388ae4af338af7502a21902977e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x32369000 - 0x3239cfff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <c295ae48e7c85c02ae396f3dae1901df> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x323b8000 - 0x323bdfff  ITSync armv6  <6f40b01e64146f50f6c31ad1cd7b17f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x324c6000 - 0x32521fff  CoreAudio armv6  <a3189b3cffe9fdb8007e8a4fd54b28e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x325b2000 - 0x325cefff  AddressBook armv6  <3023a336aec321324b5a310ee66687f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x32709000 - 0x32740fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <6ef5cd342dee1dcb8d53a54658aee417> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32773000 - 0x3282afff  Message armv6  <eee80a69c511469dacda86ea4abc5cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x328a1000 - 0x328dffff  MessageUI armv6  <7c4f809b7c62a5b3f99fd093d53b9899> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x32906000 - 0x32915fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <3c13b54df1282878fe8dfe5f4fd7e6bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3291c000 - 0x329c4fff  QuartzCore armv6  <1cf2a12e661e1a49f90553b013283b29> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32a0f000 - 0x32a11fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <eded24caed1de0629bce554de6618644> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32a16000 - 0x32a16fff  CoreSurface armv6  <2c60135f696b1a787443c4a68e1aced2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32a1b000 - 0x32a1cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <05aa0565d0f6813003dc5dc175af6048> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32a38000 - 0x32a73fff  Calendar armv6  <bad4a9d669b2597059424e547eeec039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Calendar.framework/Calendar
0x32e0c000 - 0x32f0dfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <3f78cbbe6b5b7d3b4c5753627fcebdee> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x330d8000 - 0x330e3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <8e880791fc827ae2cb63cad8f6ce5d7b> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3311e000 - 0x33213fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <3398aecf5ef07d7bbe6673fc9ab570fb> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x332c9000 - 0x33372fff  WebKit armv6  <d5aabd50737ee994787181afaf83c81e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x333d1000 - 0x3341bfff  Celestial armv6  <96b1b3694ad778d3ae6731646fcfdd8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x3358f000 - 0x3363bfff  DataAccess armv6  <5cbeac5522cbe75e90c99906b5b5ae05> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x33851000 - 0x3388efff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <5ff3f70d08b55ca7417766d4a6ba2fc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3389a000 - 0x3389dfff  MobileInstallation armv6  <f886e8377d1af59ff0c99469e8b1b105> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3415c000 - 0x34165fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <4997adf422af4a9eecf25aa9bcaf8fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3416c000 - 0x341fcfff  MapKit armv6  <36c6030a2847ef50e5b8de976f6cb685> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x346e9000 - 0x346f5fff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <d311d4de364a902ec0c0dc22079f8d73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34701000 - 0x3470bfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <4aa4e58f339a0344d7e86847e54c907d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34716000 - 0x3475afff  CoreMedia armv6  <7a9f4f7fe16ca10d9471c3248a103358> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34775000 - 0x347b1fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <4f3e66df51223dbc5232d7fb5c82113a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x347f5000 - 0x34812fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <7e34a4dd5c5b0400d10b01e998d5b2de> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34819000 - 0x3491ffff  MediaToolbox armv6  <ac956cf60c108068fbb7e90b0dc4792a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x34c0e000 - 0x34c14fff  MBX2D armv6  <6815ceba8853af0095f160b6d3c88937> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x35522000 - 0x35525fff  ActorKit armv6  <c9043ba911b8bc95ffdc28f299caf609> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3553e000 - 0x3557bfff  CoreText armv6  <c584fae4a8877461b1fc27879ac762bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x355c8000 - 0x355ccfff  IOSurface armv6  <d2585af66f593d95adf6d1fab0181b1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x356e1000 - 0x3570bfff  MIME armv6  <4c2a074d32afce77a502835f5247874a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x3580b000 - 0x35f5afff  WebCore armv6  <98f065e46e4c230bf091abaf6da60c16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x363b2000 - 0x363f7fff  iCalendar armv6  <51ba8755f9baa9d02517cd9e80a87d78> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x36422000 - 0x3647cfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <456f75f502443d281147f36f6ed4c3d3> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x36483000 - 0x36485fff  Notes armv6  <de15dc9ba3e18a4d962ceb876fc9a2b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3648a000 - 0x36493fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <2528ee7a4fd041090850f1845c393b84> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x36496000 - 0x364a6fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <44ee6b2c59cd5aa70d59f7d0d0d3b0b2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x364c1000 - 0x3655ffff  LDAP armv6  <c4d5a8dc449ceb89f87d531496c8e792> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LDAP.framework/LDAP
0x36596000 - 0x365c0fff  MobileQuickLook armv6  <86abc9b6fb4a37a971d7f6b290bb3e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x3661a000 - 0x36620fff  AccountSettings armv6  <14bd77206c288b9561e316817c89bf57> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x36646000 - 0x3664cfff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <7363aae30e9ba82d9eb1445d1d80398d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36ebb000 - 0x36ef9fff  DAVKit armv6  <edbd30dd8b12551043886ea0776575f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAVKit.framework/DAVKit
0x36f75000 - 0x36f84fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <58d1e0f460e85c5dd8cf63c7eb2fd1e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x36fac000 - 0x36fe7fff  ContentIndex armv6  <fff8b63e92ec9a8fc72d4c06d1228741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x37124000 - 0x3712efff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <9adf227705e932c47e703f73ca1d87c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3748a000 - 0x374f3fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <44d54be7409eedbf35157cc538ea660b> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37c74000 - 0x37c74fff  Accelerate armv6  <e3325738fdc407edc125d921d2a90839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37cc8000 - 0x37d0bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <5632d3e7799c5c90540157938bce4b95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x37d12000 - 0x37d12fff  vecLib armv6  <eb68bab288e9f047d876848490b162fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you want to do is to 'symbolicate' the crash dump. Then you will see references to your application code. It will actually display what your app did by references your source files and line numbers in those those files.

The easiest way to do this is to drop the crash dump on Xcode. It will add it to the Organizer and try to find the symbols.

Note that this only works if you have used 'Build and Archive' for the application version that corresponds to this crash dump.